# how to prevent user input any string that it's size more than two bytes? (two bytes only)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, input, antd

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my input that only receives two bytes characters. I've tried so many functions here but it seems not to work. For example, I have an input and I want the user just only fill it with 2 bytes characters.

Comment: So many functions? How many? Add one or more of those to your question, along with any relevant code (like the input etc) --  folks 'round here like to see that you're trying to solve it and not just asking for people to write code.

Comment: Given that JavaScript `.length` works on UCS-2 encoding, any string of length 1 is 2 bytes long.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var i = document.createElement("input");
i.type = "text";
document.body.appendChild(i);
i.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  let v = e.target.value;
  console.log(v);
  let b = (new Blob([v])).size;;
  console.log(b);
})
```